# How to setup a serial terminal for DM500HD?

Tags: terminal, serial-port

I need to connect to a Linux based STB (set-tob-box) over an emulated serial terminal. I'm not sure how to setup this connection.

The manufacturer has given me this number to use: 115200/8N1. What does this translate to? I think the first part is Baud, but what does that other stuff mean?

Also, they are using the proprietary HyperTerminal, and I want to use the free PuTTY terminal.

It is a Dream Multimedia Dreambox (DM500HD).

The settings in PuTTY:

[image: PuTTY Configuration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in that the 115200 is the baud/speed for the terminal connection.  The `8N1` is additional settings for the connection; specifically 8 data bits, No (N) parity bit, and 1 stop bit.

For more info check out Wikipedia's article on it: [8-N-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-N-1)

There's no reason you shouldn't be able to use PuTTY to do what you want (instead of HyperTerminal).

Comment: So I only need to change the Parity to None then (if you see the picture above)?

Comment: Yup, and change the baud from 9600 to 115200 (actually may not be necessary, but will be faster).  And ensure you are properly connected to the target device on COM1. :)